# Moving Solution from vs 2010 to vs 2012 gives the following error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ms-office

> Error 15 'custom ribbonclass' does not implement interface member
>   'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonComponent.RibbonUI', 
>   'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonComponent.ResumeLayout(bool)'

and many more similar errors.

Can anyone help me with this?
Here is part of the file that is giving all the errors.

from the file Stjonbord.designer.cs

```
namespace VefKennsla
{
    partial class Stjonbord : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        public Stjonbord()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.Stjornbord = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab();
            this.grBil = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup();
```

This is designer gererated code but it gives lot of errors like this line

this.Stjornbord = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab();

gives this error:
Error   36  Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab'  ...\Stjonbord.designer.cs

Comment: We need to see the relevant code for this.

Comment: Can you show the code erroring out?  No one has any context here.

Comment: It sounds like you have created a custom ribbon, using an interface and did not implement all of the required methods. But that is just a guess until you flesh out your question with some code.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. There where no problem with the solution in vs 2010.

Comment: Hi I just created new ribbon and moved code over and now everything is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that there are some problems with references. Expand the references node of the project to see if some are missing or if there is any yellow warning signs.